# What is a good plastic to use to cover computers from water leaks?

Tags: water-damage

We are having issues lately with the roof leaking. I decided I should go buy some plastic tarps or equivalent to cover every ones computers and our server racks from water damage. What plastic should I get? Not sure if there's a rule of thumb because of static electricity etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, the chance of damaging anything is likely to be low as the kit is encased and grounded so regular polythene sheeting should be OK. If there's moisture in the air, this will cut down on static build up anyway.